# PHP exec() execute last command only?

Tags: php, exec

Here is an example trying to understand `exec()` function

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    echo exec("id;ls");
?>
```

When i run this code the result of `ls` only

Does exec() execute the last command only or it executes both of them and echo the last command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**exec** returns the last line from the result of the command. You have to use *output* argument. If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.

```
exec("id;ls", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: i need  to know it returns the last line but execute both of them (`id` and `ls` )?

Comment: try my code example above and you will see that 2 commands were executed

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead for this purpose.

On the other hand, [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns only last line of the output (by default), but you can provide reference for output array as a second argument.

See the documentation for more info.

Comment: i need  to know it returns the last line but execute both of them `id` and `ls`?

Answer (score 0):

**you need write a shell script for Linux(excutable with .sh file)**